# validation Rule without making this field required

Tags: validation-rule

I have a written a validation Rule which makes the field required, Now Management want not to make this field required but when somebuddy enter the value, it should make sure that it is filled in the correct format.

Current formula:-

```
OR(
    NOT(
        REGEX(AppealDate__c, "[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}")
    ),
    VALUE(RIGHT(AppealDate__c, 2)) > 31,
    VALUE(LEFT(AppealDate__c, 2)) > 12
)
```

It's a Date field and the format should be like MM/DD. Can you help how to accomplish this goal.

Comment: If the field is of type Date, you don't need to verify its format. The format displayed depends on the user locale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are using text datatype for field AppealDate__c ,then

```
AND(NOT(ISBLANK(AppealDate__c)) ,(OR(NOT(REGEX(AppealDate__c, "[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}")),VALUE(RIGHT(AppealDate__c,2))>31,VALUE(LEFT( AppealDate__c ,2))>12)))
```

above formula will work.

Comment: This answer could be improved if you went into detail about _why_ you think this validation rule would work (as well as detail about what is different between your answer and the original validation rule provided in the question). Code dumps without explanation don't do much to help anyone grow as a programmer.

Comment: Also, the question does mention that `AppealDate__c` is, in fact, a `Date` field.

Comment: I made my assumption on formula given by @rakesh . Because he was using his field directly in regex which only accepts String as first attribute.

Comment: @DerekF how the field in format `MM/DD` can be a `Date` type?

Comment: @Oleksiy it can't (as you probably know, due to how Salesforce displays date/datetime fields). The original poster (OP) of the question is either mixing terminology, or doesn't know about how `Date` fields work in Salesforce (which Martin's comment on the question clarifies).